# How to Setup eclipse for C++ development using MinGW on windows 10

Tags: c++, eclipse

I searched a lot on this, found some tutorials and steps but nothing worked for me.

I tried with following configurations:

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

**Version**: Helios Service Release 2

**Build id**: 20110218-0911

**OS**: Windows 10

MinGW Installer

Thanks.

Comment: I'd consider trying some other IDE, which comes with MinGW and might work OOTB with it. Qt Creator installed with the Qt SDK online installer is one option, Code::Blocks or CLion might work too but I haven't tried them myself.

Comment: Qt Creator I have worked and Qt SDK comes with MinGW so its smooth to setup but Actually I want to try eclipse thats why try to setup it.